# OOPHP function no return in Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have three files: *class.php, functions.js, interface.php*

*class.php* is the oophp-file witch defines methods and attributes.

*interface.php* defines functions who uses the methods from the object of class.php

The object is defined in the index.php and is stored in a session.

With the functions.js I do POST-Calls (jQuery) on the interface.php.

My Problem:

A init()-function of interface.php is called with $.post in the functions.js
The init()-function returns the return-value of the test()-function of the object of the class.php.

**EDIT:**

the functions.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  init();
});

function init() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'interface.php',
    data: {f: 'init'},
    success: function(data) {alert(data);}
  });
}
```

the interface.php:

```
<?php
  require_once('class.php');
  session_start();

  if(isset($_REQUEST['f'])) {
    $func = $_REQUEST['f'];
    $func();
  }

  function init() {
    $obj = $_SESSION['object'];
    echo $obj->test();  // test() returns an array like array('test1', 'test2')
  }
?>
```

Whatever test() returns, in firefox I get a empty alert(). It works in Chrome!
You know the problem?

Comment: You cannot **return** data from a server-side script to a client-side one - the client only sees the **output** of the script (e.g. `echo`). The code you show therefore gives us no clue as to how the server-side code actually works.

Comment: It works in Chrome? What does `test()` do exactly (actual code)?

Comment: What does the *rest* of your code look like? At what point (if anywhere) do you parse the contents of `$_POST` to decide what function to call? (It doesn't happen on its own!)

Comment: I've updated the code above. I hope you can understand it now.

Comment: You say `$obj->test()` is an array?  Do you `json_encode` it?  If not, you should (before you echo it).

Comment: chrome is probably just all fancy and auto encoding the array youre returning.  try wrapping the array in a json_encode($array) and see if that changes your result, yo

Comment: I would highly reccomend to validate the value of $_REQUEST['f'] and not use all its possible values as a function name.